# Using Maven to run a WAR dynamically in Tomcat, how does one add classpath entries so only Tomcat sees them?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2

Scenario is such: I have a webapp that I'd like to run dynamically with the tomcat-maven-plugin's [tomcat:run goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html). The wrinkle is that I have numerous classpath resources that need to differ between the packaged artifact and the one run off a local workstation.

Failed Attempts:

1.) My first attempt was to use the builder-helper-maven-plugin, but it won't work because the target configuration files will (inconsistently!) work their way into the packaged WAR archive.

```
<plugin>    
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.3</version>
 <executions>

  <execution>     
   <id>add-resource</id>
   <phase>generate-resources</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>add-resource</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <resources>
     <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-env/${testEnv}</directory>
      <targetPath>${basedir}/target/classes</targetPath>
     </resource>
    </resources>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

2.) My second attempt was to add the folder (since the files-to-be-deployed aren't present in Tomcat's classpath yet either) to -Djava.ext.dirs, but it has no effect (I actually suspect that this `systemProperties` element is misconfigured or otherwise not working at all). See:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
 <configuration>
  <tomcatWebXml>${basedir}/src/main/mock/web.xml</tomcatWebXml>

  <systemProperties>
   <property>
    <name>java.ext.dirs</name>
    <value>${basedir}/src/main/resources-env/${testEnv}</value>
   </property>      
  </systemProperties>      
  <path>/licensing</path>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm not sure what to attempt next. The heart of the problem seems to be that missing in this plugin is something like Surefire's `<additionalClasspathElement>` element.

Would the next step be to create a custom catalina.properties and add it to a `<configurationDir>`? If so, what would catalina.properties need to look like?

### Edit: More thorough explanation follows

I understand this question reads somewhat vaguely, so I'll try to elaborate a bit.

My POM uses the webResources functionality of the WAR plugin to copy some environment-specific config files and without using a profile to do it, by copying in a resource named `/src/main/resources-env/${env}` like so:

```
...
<plugin>    
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
    <configuration>
            ...
        <webResources>
            <!-- Copy Environment-specific resources to classes -->
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-env/${env}</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will copy the (default, DEV) environment resources into the package and currently works fine. Note also that b/c these occur as part of packaging, the `tomcat:run` goal is never privy to them (which is desired, as the environments differ).

So the problem is this: when the dynamic `tomcat:run` is executed, the application will fail because its classpath (it looks at `target/classes`) will lack the needed local workstation environmental config files. All I need to do is get those on the path for tomcat, but would like to do so without adding anything to the command line and *definitely* without breaking the build's integrity if someone follows up with a `mvn package` and doesn't `clean` first.

I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be missing something but why don't you declare the required dependencies in a profile and use this profile when running Tomcat? I don't get why you would need to put these resources at Tomcat's classpath level.

**UPDATE:** I'm editing my answer to cover the comment from the OP itself answering my question above.

> You're correct, the files really need to be in the webapp classpath, not tomcat's. So how could I make a profile that activate automatically for tomcat:run but without additional cmd line args?

I don't know how to do this without declaring the profile as `<activeByDefault>` or listing it under the `<activeProfiles>` (but this is not what I had in mind, I would rather use property activation and call something like `mvn tomcat:run -Denv=test`, not sure to understand why this is a problem).

> And how should I "declare the dependencies" in the profile while ensuring that subsequent invocations never let them into the package WAR via a vanilla mvn package

If the previously mentioned profile is active by default, then you'll need to exclude it if you don't want it, by calling something like `mvn package -P !profile-1`. A profile can't be magically deactivated for one particular goal (at least, not to my knowledge).

Actually, my understanding is that you really have two different context here: the "testing" context (where you want to include more things in the WAR) and the "normal" context (where you don't want these things to be included). To be honest, I don't know how you could distinguish these two situations without specifying any additional parameter (either to activate a profile or to deactivate it depending on the context). You must have valid reasons but, as I said, I don't really understand why this is a problem. So maybe profiles are not a solution for your situation. But I'd really like to understand why because this seems to be a typical use case for profiles :)

**UPDATE2:** Having read your comment to the other answer and your update, I realize that my initial understanding was wrong (I though you were talking about dependencies in the maven sense). But, I still think that profiles could help you, for example to customize the `<resources>` as in this [blog post](http://thedevelopercorner.blogspot.com/2007/02/maven-profiles.html) (this is just one way to do, using a property like `src/main/resources/${env}` in the path is another way to go). But this won't solve **all** your concerns (like not specifying additional command line params or  automagically cleaning the target directory). I don't have any solutions for that.

Comment: You're correct, the files really need to be in the webapp classpath, not tomcat's. So how could I make a profile that activate automatically for tomcat:run but without additional cmd line args? And how should I "declare the dependencies" in the profile while ensuring that subsequent invocations never let them into the package WAR via a vanilla `mvn package`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm fine with adding a profile to do this conditionally just as you described (was hoping to keep this hidden from developer users, but I relent). I'll give that a try now.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependencies element directly to the plugin element.

Here is an example of doing the same with the Jetty plugin from the (still in development) Maven Handbook:  http://www.sonatype.com/books/mhandbook-stage/reference/ch06s03.html

Comment: Apologies, as I used the word dependency generally, and not to describe a Maven Dependency proper. Since what I need added to the classpath is actually a folder of configuration files (to be loaded as class path resources), will this approach (or something like it) work?

Answer (score 1):

Vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MTOMCAT-77 which addresses this need.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution I have in place at the moment.

Special thanks to Pascal's diligent conversation here, but I ultimately decided to make a change to how I was loading my environment-specific config files throughout the goals and now I believe I'm getting most of what I initially wanted.

I removed the config files from `<webResources>` from the WAR plugin and the test config from `<testResources>` and am now manually managing the resource-copying with the the maven-resources-plugin to copy them directly into `target/classes` at the goal they're needed. This way Tomcat can see the config, but the tests aren't broken by having duplicate or differing config files on the path.

It's definitely a mess, but it works. Listing:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-env-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-env/${env}</directory>                                 
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-testEnv-resources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-env/${testEnv}</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-env-resources-again</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-env/${env}</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>                            
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So a `mvn clean install` will build and test with ${env} and ${testEnv} appropriately. A `mvn -Denv=someLocalConfig tomcat:run` (which in my case is identical to my default ${testEnv} will make sure the `src/main/resources-env/someLocalConfig` gets loaded for Tomcat's dynamic execution, but without requiring that I do a clean before successfully rebuilding.

Like I said, messy that I'm rewriting the same cluster of files to the same target location at each phase, but it accomplishes what I'd meant to.