# Maven tomcat plugin - adding extra classpath

Tags: tomcat, plugins, maven

I'm wondering if it's possible to add an extra directory to the classpath of tomcat run by the maven tomcat plugin?

When I use "normal" tomcat 6, I set this via the bin/setClasspath.sh file, and it's pretty straightforward that way, but so far I haven't been able to figure it out how to do this when using maven.

So any help is appreciated!

cheers,

balázs

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [classesDir](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#classesDir) parameter for the plugin configuration ([tomcat-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/)).

Comment: looks nice. is this overwriting the existing classesDir or extending it? if the latter, can you list more dirs?

Comment: @khmarbaise does not seem to work for me. do you configure it like this? <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>run</goal></goals> <configuration> <classesDir>/opt/config/</classesDir> </configuration> </execution> </executions>

Comment: I'm having the same issue here I tried with additionalClasspathDirs and additionalClassesDirs. When I tried to use classpath:someResource the error is always the same FileNotFoundException: class path resource someResource cannot be opened because it does not exist. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question and the first (not accepted) answer. Maven profiles FTW!

[Using Maven to run a WAR dynamically in Tomcat, how does one add classpath entries so only Tomcat sees them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923302/using-maven-to-run-a-war-dynamically-in-tomcat-how-does-one-add-classpath-entrie)